# Connecting oracle from windows 2008 r2 server, Do i have to install oracle client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, windows-server-2008

I am very new to oracle.

This is the current situation:

1- I have got a server (windows 2008 r2)

2- There is another server which is running oracle database

I have created a test web application which is connecting to oracle. I have installed Oracle client 12.1.0 on my desktop.

I have added the reference of Oracle.DataAccess.dll (4) and actual file into my bin folder and tried to connect to the oracle database and it worked on my desktop. I have uploaded the files on to the server and I get errors

I tried the above process for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, and i get the same result. it works on local but it does not when i upload it to the server.

My question is: Do i have to install oracle client to the windows 2008 r2 server in order to be able to connect to an Oracle database which is located somewhere else?

Comment: oracle client is necessary when it is other than server which contains oracle.

Comment: can i not add the necessary files into the project? instead of installing the oracle client?

Comment: Of course you need it, when installing it you should consider the Oracle database version on the server and also the OS in case of 32 or 64 bit on which you want to install oracle client on it, also pay attention to the oracle DLLs of your application

Comment: We don't know enough to know to answer your question. 'created a test web application which is connecting to oracle' - connecting, HOW exactly? You can connect to Oracle Database with ODBC and JDBC drivers which don't require any other install, including the Client (Instant or Full.)

Comment: I use C# and ASP to develop the project. I am not using Java, is there any way that i can run the website without installing the oracle client?